# How to render a recharts graph in a pdf using react-pdf

Tags: reactjs, recharts, react-pdf

I have been using the recharts library for the dashboards in a NextJs app and a new requirement came through to download tables and charts through a PDF.

On the github for the react-pdf there was an issued raised that has now been closed due to the newly release of SVG support in the package where the author states the bindings should be done separately and people have achieved this.

- Solved GitHub issue: https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/669
- SVG example: https://react-pdf.org/repl?example=svg

So far I have go the PDF rendering simple content such as text. Note: to get the react-pdf to work in this sandbox you might need to open it in a new window.
https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-line-chart-forked-vifo9?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I am in an almost identical predicament.

Comment: Not yet, I'm currently using a convert to PNG function then loading the PNG into the PDF.

Comment: @Leonardo Hello. I also have the same problem. Do you have other workaround about this?